# Write SQL query to fetch data from below table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
column1 column2 column3
A           B     50
B           A     50
C           D     50
D           C     10
```

From above table,write a query to fetch data as

```
column1 column2 column3
A        B        100
C        D         60
```

or

```
column1 column2 column3
B        A        100
D        C         60
```

Comment: How much is the paycheck ?

Comment: Homework? Did you try anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the complete solution. Just a hint for you to do your homework.

```
select a.column3 + b.column3 from
mytable a, mytable b
where a.column1 = b.column2
and a.column2 = b.column1;
```